# Use template parameter of template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm currently playing around with `template`s in C++ and got stuck with `template template parameters`.

Lets say I have the following classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyInterface
{
    virtual T Foo() = 0;
}

class MyImpl : public MyInterface<int>
{
public:
    int Foo() { /*...*/ }
};

template< template<typename T> typename ImplType>
class MyHub
{
public:
    static T Foo()
    {
        ImplType i;
        return i.Foo();
    }

private:
    MyHub() { }
    ~MyHub() { }
};
```

In essence I would like to have a `static class` like `MyHub` that accepts an implementation of `MyInterface` and provides certain `static` methods to use them like `static T Foo()`.

Then I tried to use `MyHub`:

```
int main()
{
    int i = MyHub<MyImpl>::Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I always end up getting an error saying that the type `T` (of `static T Foo()` in MyHub) does not name a type.

I would expect that it works because

- the template parameter of the template parameter `Impl` is named T
- `MyHub` is a templated class with one template parameter and contains a method `Foo`

So far I couldn't find a solution for this after digging through documentations and google results so I hope some of you can help me.

Comment: The problem begins with `MyHub<MyImpl>::Foo()`, where `MyImpl` is not a class template, but a type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use typedefs. Also, since your implementation classes are not template class, there is no need for template template parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct MyInterface
{
    virtual T Foo() = 0;
    typedef T Type;
};

class MyIntImpl : public MyInterface<int>
{
public:
    int Foo() { return 2; }
};

class MyStringImpl : public MyInterface<std::string>
{
public:
    std::string Foo() { return "haha"; }
};

template<class ImplType>
class MyHub
{
public:
    static typename ImplType::Type Foo()
    {
        ImplType i;
        return i.Foo();
    }

private:
    MyHub() { }
    ~MyHub() { }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyHub<MyIntImpl>::Foo() << "\n"; // prints 2
    std::cout << MyHub<MyStringImpl>::Foo() << "\n"; // print haha
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](http://cpp.sh/5yka) is an example.

Comment: You mean `typenames` rather than `typedefs`?

Comment: The base class `MyInterface` has a typedef for its template type parameter. Hence I mentioned typedefs.

Comment: `auto` can replace `typename ImplType::Type` in C++14.

Answer (score 3):

The STL uses value_type as a place holder for the underlying type of a template class. You could possibly do the same for your solution.

```
template<typename T>
struct MyInterface
{
    typedef T value_type;
    virtual T Foo() = 0;
}

class MyImpl : public MyInterface<int>
{
public:
    int Foo() { /*...*/ }
};

template<typename ImplType>
class MyHub
{
public:
    static typename ImplType::value_type Foo()
    {
        ImplType i;
        return i.Foo();
    }

private:
    MyHub() { }
    ~MyHub() { }
};
```

Also note that in c++14, `typename ImplType::value_type` can be replaced by `auto`:

```
static auto Foo()
{
    ImplType i;
    return i.Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`MyImpl` is not a class template; so can't be passed as the template parameter of `MyInterface`.

You could change your `MyInterface`, `MyImpl` and `MyHub` classes to:

```
template<typename T>
class MyInterface{
    public:
        virtual T foo() = 0;
};

class MyImpl: public MyInterface<int>{
    public:
        using value_type = int;

        value_type foo(){ return 1; /* dummy */ }
};

template<typename Impl, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Impl, MyInterface<typename Impl::value_type>>::value>>
class MyHub{
    public:
        static auto foo(){
            static Impl i;
            return i.foo();
        }
};
```

Which lets you use it the same way you are in your example.

The `std::is_base_of` check might be a little unnecessary in this case; but, this way you can't accidentally pass in another class that isn't derived from `MyInterface` with a method `foo()`.

Comment: `static_assert` would provide simpler error message than `enable_if_t`.

Answer (score 2):

The names of template parameters of template template parameters are effectively a purely documentational construct—they don't get included in the containing template's scope.

There's good reason for that: there is nothing to whcih they could refer in the containing template. When you have a template template parameter, you must pass a *template* as the argument to it, and not an *instantiation* of a template. In other words, you're passing a template *without arguments* as the argument.

This means your code is simply wrong—you're using `MyImpl` as an argument for `MyHub`, but `MyImpl` is a *class.* `MyHub` expects a *template,* not a *class.* The correct instantiation of `MyHub` would be `MyHub<MyInterface>`. Not that there are no template arguments after this use of `MyInterface`; we are passing in the template itself, not an instantiation of it.

Template template parameters are used rather rarely in practice. You only use them if you want to instantiate the parameter template with your own types. So I would expect your `MyHub` code to do something like this:

```
template <template <class> class ImplTemplate>
struct MyHub
{
  typedef ImplTemplate<SomeMyHub_SpecificType> TheType;
  // ... use TheType
};
```

This doesn't seem to be what you want to do. I believe you want a normal type template parameter, and provide a nested typedef for its `T`. Like this:

```
template <class T>
struct MyInterface
{
  typedef T ParamType;  // Added

  virtual T Foo() = 0;
};


template<class ImplType>
class MyHub
{
    typedef typename ImplType::ParamType T;
public:
    static T Foo()
    {
        ImplType i;
        return i.Foo();
    }

private:
    MyHub() { }
    ~MyHub() { }
};

int main()
{
    int i = MyHub<MyImpl>::Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Template template parameters are used rather rarely in practice. You only use them if you want to instantiate the parameter template with your own types.*" Or if you want to capture the template template's template arguments for other purposes via specialization.

Comment: @ildjarn I don't quite follow, can you please provide an example? A template template parameter does not really *have* arguments.

Comment: `template<class> struct arg_tuple; template<template<class...> class TT, class... Args> struct arg_tuple<TT<Args...>> { /* Args pack now available for inspection/manipulation, e.g.: */ using type = std::tuple<Args...>; };`